# Unity. Partycle System

Tags: unity3d

Как при помощи системы частиц реализовать вот такой вот эффект как на видео?
https://vk.com/video174341022_456239044
Картинка объекта должна распыляться на множество маленьких картинок, чтобы некоторые картинки закручивались в случайном порядке и на случайную дистанцию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не совсем верно поняли этот эффект.
Картинка здесь не распыляется, а просто исчезает, а на её месте появляется Particle Emitter, который выстреливает конусом частицы, которые выглядят, как кусочек картинки.

Почитайте подробнее в документации о том, что такое [ParticleSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-ParticleSystem.html).

- За направление и зону сауна частиц отвечает модуль [Shape](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/PartSysShapeModule.html).
- За закручивание картинок в зависимости от длительности жизни модуль
  [Rotation Over Lifetime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/PartSysRotOverLifeModule.html). В документации описано, как сделать так,
  чтобы сделать значения случайными.
- За то, чтобы они летели на случайную дистанцию отвечает поле "StartLifetime" модуля [Main](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/PartSysMainModule.html). В этом модуле нужно сменить тип значения с Constant на любой другой вариант. В итоге частицы будут иметь разную длительность жизни и
  будут исчезать на разной дистанции от эмитера.
- Что именно
  спаунится выбирается в модуле [Renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/PartSysRendererModule.html) в поле Material